# How to List all software installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and Uninstall them

Tags: software-center, uninstall, software-sources, lamp, phpmyadmin

I am beginner to Ubuntu. I have installed ubuntu desktop 14.04 and have tried to install PHP, Apache, MYSQL and PHPMYADMIN through terminal. I have tried many commands but have only installed Apache and php.

After some time i see that i have installed these software in many directories. So Now i want to see the list of All these software installed on my system and uninstall them and then install in a secure Way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open up a terminal and type,

```
 $ dpkg --list
```

to list all the installed packages.

To completely remove the package you want, type:

```
 $ sudo apt-get purge <package_name>
```

For example,

```
 $ sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

Also, the easiest way to install these services is using tasksel,

```
 $ sudo apt-get install tasksel
 $ sudo tasksel
   (Select LAMP server and follow instructions)
 $ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 7):

Open up [Ubuntu software center](http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshots/s/software-center/10676_large.png). Go to `Installed` tab and in the search, simply type `*` (asterick), the software center will show up all the installed software by category.
To uninstall any software, simply highlight it and click `Remove`.

Answer (score 3):

To list all packages, type the following command in the terminal:

```
$ sudo dpkg --list
```

To remove package:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove package-name
```

To remove package along with its configuration files if there is any:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge package-name
```